# How to append line in one file to the same line number on the other file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
file3 = open("over_speeding.txt", "r")
file5 = open("fine.txt", "r")
file6 = open("all details.txt", "a")
x, y = file3.readlines(), file5.readlines()
if file6 == file6.close(): #this just an argument to get the if loop going
     print("not working")

else:
     num = 0 # the of the file that will be appended
     file6.write(y[num] + x[num])
     num += 1

file3.close()
file5.close()
file6.close()
file6 = open("all details.txt", "r")
file66 = file6.read()
print(file66)
```

here i am trying to merge two 4 lined files into a new file, where for example the first line of file5 is appended with the first line in file3 and so on.

at the if loop I want to check weather the file6 is open or not, this is not working, can you show me another more argument that i can possibly use. i have tried to output into a file without the aid of the loop but this is very inefficient and the format that is outputted is very hard to change.

at the else loop if the file is not closed the information in the lines of file3 and file5 will be appended according to the variable num whih increases by 1 and will stop if num = 4, i have not written the code for it because i do not know how to.

the error that is outputted in the shell is:

```
file6.write(y[num] + x[num])
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

can you fix this error and if possible use show me how to use the for or while loop on this instead of an if loop

Comment: what do you mean when you write "if loop"? There is no loop in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest # izip_longest in Python2

with open("over_speeding.txt") as speeding, open("fine.txt") as fine, open("all details.txt", "a") as everything:
    for speedline, fineline in zip_longest(speeding, fine, fillvalue=""):
        everything.write(speedline.strip() + fineline.strip() + "\n")
```

Comment: just saved my life zondo. i have been at it for 3 days now. its a relief.

Comment: I really enjoy this snippet- clear and short. Bookmarked!

Comment: @TheZombro: I'm flattered.  No one's ever said that to me before.

Comment: @zondo You're a helpful individual, i'd buy you a coffee